# Why is an object pushed when you push it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

According to Newton's third law, if I push an object the object should push me back with the same and opposite force. So there should be no net force, which means that it shouldn't be displaced (pushed).

But in reality it's not!!! How do I understand this?

Answer (score 1):

Action and Reaction Forces are equal and opposite, but they **do not cancel out each other**.

The action here actes on the box, while the reaction acts on the hand, so they **cannot cancel out each other**.

The box moves because of the action force.